# Get objects which are in both lists based on specific comparator

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two `List` objects, `listA` and `listB`, which contain a collection of `User` objects.

Each `User` object has a property `ID`.

I want to get a list of users which are present in both `listA` and `listB` based on their `ID` property.

Here is my code so far:

```
listA.Where(a => listB.Any(b => b.ID == a.ID));
```

Is there a better way to do this? It feels like it could be inefficient, especially if `listB` is large.

The `User` object does not implement `IEquatable`.

Comment: Are the IDs unique? Could maybe use a HashSet instead with the ID as the key.

Comment: The IDs are unique `Guid` objects. If two `User` objects have the same `ID` then they are the same (but not directly equatable).

Comment: Then create two HashSets with the IDs as the key, use the method you've shown but compare the keys. Or as other people have pointed out `Intersect()` might be better. Haven't tested this hence a comment only.

Comment: The library that I am using gives me the users as `List` objects so I think manually converting them to `HashSet` objects would negate any performance improvements, surely?

Comment: What is it with the upvotes today? _"Ooh cool, I would like to know this too"_ does not make something a good question. This question has been asked plenty of times before. See also [C# Linq intersect/except with one part of object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633375/c-sharp-linq-intersect-except-with-one-part-of-object).

Comment: Oh, that's probably true. Wasn't aware you were limited to lists. I'll tap out then.

Comment: @CodeCaster my object does not implement `IEquatable`. This is not a duplicate of your linked question.

Comment: Then you create a new `IEqualityComparer<User>` and pass that to `Intersect()`. That variant of the same question has been asked enough times as well. See also [Using LINQ to objects Intersect and Except on a specific property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998232/using-linq-to-objects-intersect-and-except-on-a-specific-property),

Comment: Maybe I'm going blind @CodeCaster, I can't see where that linked answer explains about creating an `IEqualityComparer` and passing it into `Intersect`.

Comment: [The first one I linked to after you said `User` doesn't implement `IEquatable<User>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633375/c-sharp-linq-intersect-except-with-one-part-of-object). Look; you can try and spend your effort in battling my duplicate close vote which I'm not going to retract, because this question is not unique, and plenty of questions deal with this very subject. I'd advise you to read those questions instead. I'm not here to fight you; I'm here to fight duplication.

Answer (score 3):

If `User` implements `IEquatable<User>`, assumption is that two `User` are the same if `ID` are the same, then you can use LINQ `Intersect`. For example:

```
listA.Intersect(listB);
```

If `User` does not implement `IEquatable<User>` you can invoke `Intersect` with `IEqualityComparer<User>`. For Example:

```
listA.Intersect(listB, new UserEqualityComparer());
```

where

```
UserEqualityComparer : IEquatable<User> {...}
```

Comment: `User` doesn't implement `IEquatable<User>`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var result = listA.Intersect(listB);
```

Assuming that your `User` class implements the `IEquatable<User>`

if this is not your case, then you can do something like that n order to intersect both lists based on the ID value:

```
var result = listA.Select(s1 => s1.ID).ToList().Intersect(listB.Select(s2 => s2.ID).ToList()).ToList();
```

This is creating two new lists of the ID values in both lists, and get the intersection between them.

Comment: The `User` must implement `IEquatable<User>`, otherwise this wont work if users are different instances.

Comment: @Lepijohnny: yes correct, I will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to `Join` on Id property of both collections..

```
var results = listA.Join(listB, a => a.Id, b=> b.Id, (a, b) => a);
```